# How do I get SPM to build a library and executable with the same name?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a SPM project where I'm producing both an command line program and an API. Ideally I'd like the command line program, the API file and Swift import to all be the same. ie. I'd like my command line program to be `simulacra`, the library to be called `Simulacra` and the Swift import for it to be `import Simulacra`.

But I'm having problems getting that to work. Here's my current `Package.swift`:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "Simulacra",
    products: [
        .executable(name: "simulacra", targets: ["Simulacra-cmd", "Simulacra"]),
        .library(name: "Simulacra", targets: ["Simulacra"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Simulacra",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "Sources"
        ),
        .executableTarget(
            name: "Simulacra-cmd",
            dependencies: [
                "Simulacra",
            ],
            path: "cmd"
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Simulacra-tests",
            dependencies: [
                "Simulacra",
            ],
            path: "Tests"
        ),
    ]
)
```

I've found that if I rename the library to `SimulacraCore` it all works, however the import is then `import SimulacraCore`. As it stands Xcode has all sorts of problems compiling and build and when I built the tests, it actually dumps all the build artefacts into the root of the project instead of the derived data directories. Other things that occur include errors from the build indicating it can't find the `Simulacra` library, or trying to import a lower case name `simulacra` instead.

Has anyone tried anything like this?

Comment: It seems your question contains a solution: If products have different names (assuming they're case-insensitive), the main problem is solved, is that correct?

Comment: Yes in a sense, using different names does fix the problem, but not solve it if I want to have the same name. I've yet to confirm, but I have been told that this is an Xcode thing and that it's fine from a command line built.